# Compress a folder into separated parts ( no need to be all parts together to extract)

Tags: java, zip

In my application I can compress a folder and its contents,
this content is the result of manipulation of pdf, jpg and xls. However
I needed to split it into pieces (the compressed file can not be
greater than for example 10 MB), but in such a way that a part can be
extracted without the need of the other. I can also with another
class compact in parts but with the need of all parts
together to be able to extract. This class is the one I use to create a single file.

The question is how to achieve to zip the folder into parts that can be later extracted wiithout the need of the other parts.My code so far can just zip the folder into one single part.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipCompress {
    public static void compress(String dirPath, String zipName,String path) {
        Path sourceDir = Paths.get(dirPath);
        String zipFileName = path+zipName.concat(".zip");
        try {
            ZipOutputStream outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));
            Files.walkFileTree(sourceDir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attributes) {
                    try {
                        Path targetFile = sourceDir.relativize(file);
                        outputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(targetFile.toString()));
                        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
                        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        outputStream.closeEntry();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

Solved to list the files in the folder (folder containing the files I want to compress), after this create a new folder and move the files until the accumulated size is "5 MB", each time the accumulated size of the files is larger than "5 mb" create a new folder and move the files to this new folder.
I am sure my codes can be improved, so i accept suggestions.

```
    public void listNovo() throws IOException {
    File directory = new File("D:\\Faturas\\Gerados\\");
    String pasta = "\\Pasta";
    long length = 0;
    long fileSizeInBytes = 0;
    long fileSizeInMB = 0;
    long fileSizeInKB = 0;
    int count = 0;

    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        String fileName1 = file.getName();
        if (file.isFile()) {
            length += file.length();
            System.out.println("file:" + file.getName());
            fileSizeInBytes = length;
            fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
            fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
            System.out.println("fileSizeInMB:" + fileSizeInMB);
            if (fileSizeInMB < 5) {
                File diretorio = new File(jTCaminho.getText() + pasta + count);
                if (!diretorio.exists()) {
                    new File(jTCaminho.getText() + pasta + count).mkdir();
                    Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(diretorio.toString(), fileName1), REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    length += fileSizeInMB;
                }
                else if (diretorio.exists()) {
                    Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(diretorio.toString(), fileName1), REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    length += fileSizeInMB;
                }
            }

            if (fileSizeInMB >= 5) {
                fileSizeInMB = 0;
                length=0;
                   count++;
                if (fileSizeInMB < 5) {
                    File diretorio = new File(jTCaminho.getText() + pasta + count);
                    if (!diretorio.exists()) {
                        new File(jTCaminho.getText() + pasta + count).mkdir();
                        Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(diretorio.toString(), fileName1), REPLACE_EXISTING);
                        length += fileSizeInMB;
                    }
                   else if (diretorio.exists()) {
                        Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(diretorio.toString(), fileName1), REPLACE_EXISTING);
                        length += fileSizeInMB;
                    }
                }
            }
        }//fim isFile
    }//fim directoryListfile
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the code not work, what specifically does not work, does it throw an exception or behaves unexpected in a different way?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: you need to write the logic to split the files into groups of files that are at most 10mb big and zip each one independently.

Comment: Working on it, as soon as i can will add the code here, emaybe not fully working

Comment: Code updated on que question